# Javascript chrome extension: problems in timing code after page reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, timing

I am trying to write a simple chrome extension to practice with javascript, since I already have basic skills in C and I would like to learn JS too. The extension I'm planning to write should simply work on expedia website (expedia.it in my case), making a search and returning a specific result in an output file, let's say in a spreadsheet. This is what I've written so far:

**Manifest.json:**

```
{
"name":"Myextension",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description":"extension sample",
"icons":{ "16":"icon16.png" },
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["*://www.expedia.it/*"],
        "js":["script.js"]
    }
    ]
}
```

**script.js:**

```
function refine(){
document.getElementById("inpHotelMirror").value='refinedsearch';
}
document.getElementById('package-departing').value='date1';
document.getElementById('package-returning').value='date2';
document.getElementById('search-button').click();
```

As the code shows, it should write in input "date1" and "date2" (to be defined before launching the extension) and then submit the form. Until here, everything is ok, it works and the search begins. The problem is that I want to launch the *refine* function **after** the page has reloaded, which takes about 10-15 seconds. In order to do that I tried setTimeout, setInterval, window.onload and other tricks like a while loop to make the function write the input after the page has loaded, but none of these seems to work. I've searched many times questions similar to mine, but still couldn't solve the problem. Is this a problem of my code and I should change it, or is this a problem with the website, preventing similar scripts?

I apologise for being a newbie, and thanks for helping.

**EDIT:**
I tried adding the run_at line, then calling the refine function with a setTimeout. Now the extension doesn't work, neither the first part that was actually working. I also tried the document_idle version, now the first part works again but the second still doesn't; it seems like there are problems while injecting the code in the reloaded page.

Comment: Why do you need to use setTimeout? What are you waiting for? If the script is injected at `document_end` all the DOM you need should be available, the rest is just images.

Comment: Sounds like the element is added via js dynamically, so you'll need to use MutationObserver.

Comment: @MrMisterMan I tried document_end with andwithout the setTimeout, doesn't work in both ways.

Comment: @wOxxOm So I should use MutationObserver by calling the refine function every time the DOM mutates, is it right?

Comment: Does your content script continue to run after the page changes, or does it run *again*? The difference is if the page is changed dynamically using AJAX, or if the page actually reloads. If you are unable to determine this from just observing the page's behavior, you can test this by adding some delays and perhaps some logging to the console. What will be needed will be different depending on which method is used to update the page to the results. If AJAX is used, your script will be continuing to run (if there is anything that is delayed in execution).

Comment: @tr1nity, re: calling the refine function, yes, in this particular case it'll work, but first check if getElementById returns something since the callback will be getting hundreds of mutations.

Comment: @Makyen by observing the page behavior, it seems like I am sent to a new page as the submit button is clicked, then there is some sort of loading that lasts for about 10 seconds, but I think the page doesn't reload again. Moreover, by inspecting page, I could see that the code changes after the click (maybe to prepare the new page) and then remain almost the same until results are shown, with just a few little differences. Is this enough to determine which method should be used?

Comment: @wOxxOm well, I've never used MutationObserver so I may experience some difficulties... Which one might be a simple way to check if getEl is returning something?